# In unix platform using perl, from snmp::getTrapdLog i have to grep for INTEGER: levels corresponding to their Hex-STRING values

Tags: awk, grep, snmp, snmp-trap

Here from the below log I have to grep for INTEGER: level1(1) and Hex-STRING: `22 22 22 22 22 22 00 00`  and compare both.

In my case, If INTEGER: level1(1)  corresponds to Hex-STRING: `22 22 22 22 22 22 00 00` then the check point should pass. So how can i achieve this?

Log:

```
ADM-LINUX (01:50:05): SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (21267) 0:03:32.67   SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: ISIS-MIB::isisAdjacencyChange  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationSysLevelIndex.0 = **INTEGER: level1(1)**  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationCircIfIndex.0 = Gauge32: 67108873     ISIS-MIB::isisPduLspId.0 = **Hex-STRING: 22 22 22 22 22 22 00 00**  ISIS-MIB::isisAdjState.0 = INTEGER: up(3)
ADM-LINUX (01:50:05): 2014-03-12 14:21:04 172.16.246.121 [172.16.246.121]:
ADM-LINUX (01:50:05): SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (21269) 0:03:32.69   SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: ISIS-MIB::isisAdjacencyChange  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationSysLevelIndex.0 = INTEGER: level2(2)  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationCircIfIndex.0 = Gauge32: 67108874     ISIS-MIB::isisPduLspId.0 = Hex-STRING: 22 22 22 22 22 24 00 00  ISIS-MIB::isisAdjState.0 = INTEGER: up(3)
ADM-LINUX (01:50:05): 2014-03-12 14:21:04 172.16.246.121 [172.16.246.121]:
ADM-LINUX (01:50:05): SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (21271) 0:03:32.71   SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: ISIS-MIB::isisAdjacencyChange  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationSysLevelIndex.0 = INTEGER: level1(1)  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationCircIfIndex.0 = Gauge32: 67108875     ISIS-MIB::isisPduLspId.0 = Hex-STRING: 22 22 22 22 22 25 00 00  ISIS-MIB::isisAdjState.0 = INTEGER: up(3)
ADM-LINUX (01:50:05): 2014-03-12 14:21:04 172.16.246.121 [172.16.246.121]:
ADM-LINUX (01:50:05): SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (21272) 0:03:32.72   SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: ISIS-MIB::isisAdjacencyChange  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationSysLevelIndex.0 = INTEGER: level2(2)  ISIS-MIB::isisNotificationCircIfIndex.0 = Gauge32: 67108875     ISIS-MIB::isisPduLspId.0 = Hex-STRING: 22 22 22 22 22 25 00 00  ISIS-MIB::isisAdjState.0 = INTEGER: up(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
awk '/level1\(1\)/ && /22 22 22 22 22 22 00 00/ {print "ok"}' file
```

It will test all line and if one line does contain both `level1(1)` and `22 22 22 22 22 22 00 00` print `ok`

To make it more exact, you can use:

```
awk '/INTEGER: level1\(1\)/ && /Hex-STRING: 22 22 22 22 22 22 00 00/ {print "ok"}' file
```

---

If you like to store it in a variable:

```
test=$(awk '{f+=(/level1\(1\)/ && /22 22 22 22 22 22 00 00/)?1:0} END {print f}' file)
echo $test
1
```

variable `test` will be `1` or more if regex is true.